# Spatie media library retrieve image on cPanel production 404 not found

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I have a Laravel application where I am using spatie media Library.

my APP_URL in local is https://example.test

when I do ```$user->getFirstMediaUrl('images')

it gives me something like this

https://example.test/storage/1/medialibraryFgTy

which when opened shows the image

in production however same thing shows 404 not found

my APP_URL in production is https://example.com

https://example.com/storage/1/medialibraryFgTy

How to resolve this issue. is this cPanel issue?

Comment: Have you run `php artisan storage:link` in your production enviroment?

Comment: Yes I did but still same issue